# What should I say?

Tags: word-usage, spoken-english

I unexpectedly met my friend.
My friend needs to go somewhere else, and has no time to chat.
What should I say to them?
Should I say "Hi!", because I just met them, or say "Bye!", because he's about to leave?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say both!

Honestly, those little meetings can be kind of frantic, it's perfectly OK to say something like:

> "*Hi, so good to see you... looks like you're busy though, so bye!*"

Or even

> "*Hi! Bye!*"